# Problem on "deploy dcos installation"

Tags: server, docker

before I explain the error that I had received, here is my setup for DCOS installation > 1Master , 3Agent
and i run the following command

```
bash dcos_generate_config.sh --deploy
```

which resulted in this error, my master node run just fine and dcos is installed in that node however my 3 agent node face problems.

```
 ====> 10.50.1.7:22 FAILED
     TASK:
/usr/bin/ssh -oConnectTimeout=10 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -oBatchMode=yes -oPasswordAuthentication=no -p22 -i genconf/ssh_key -tt root@10.50.1.7 sudo bash /opt/dcos_install_tmp/dcos_install.sh slave
     STDERR:
          Connection to 10.50.1.7 closed.
     STDOUT:
          Starting DC/OS Install Process
          Running preflight checks
          /opt/dcos_install_tmp/dcos_install.sh: line 252: getenforce: command not found
          Checking Docker is configured with a production storage driver: WARNING: No swap limit support
          Creating directories under /etc/mesosphere
          Creating role file for slave
          Configuring DC/OS
          Setting and starting DC/OS
          Warning: dcos-link-env.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
          Job for dcos-link-env.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status dcos-link-env.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
====> 10.50.1.4:22 FAILED
     TASK:
/usr/bin/ssh -oConnectTimeout=10 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -oBatchMode=yes -oPasswordAuthentication=no -p22 -i genconf/ssh_key -tt root@10.50.1.4 sudo bash /opt/dcos_install_tmp/dcos_install.sh slave
     STDERR:
          Connection to 10.50.1.4 closed.
     STDOUT:
          Starting DC/OS Install Process
          Running preflight checks
          /opt/dcos_install_tmp/dcos_install.sh: line 252: getenforce: command not found
          Checking Docker is configured with a production storage driver: WARNING: No swap limit support
          Creating directories under /etc/mesosphere
          Creating role file for slave
          Configuring DC/OS
          Setting and starting DC/OS
          Warning: dcos-link-env.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
          Job for dcos-link-env.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status dcos-link-env.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
====> 10.50.1.8:22 FAILED
     TASK:
/usr/bin/ssh -oConnectTimeout=10 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -oBatchMode=yes -oPasswordAuthentication=no -p22 -i genconf/ssh_key -tt root@10.50.1.8 sudo bash /opt/dcos_install_tmp/dcos_install.sh slave
     STDERR:
          Connection to 10.50.1.8 closed.
     STDOUT:
          Starting DC/OS Install Process
          Running preflight checks
          /opt/dcos_install_tmp/dcos_install.sh: line 252: getenforce: command not found
          Checking Docker is configured with a production storage driver: WARNING: No swap limit support
          Creating directories under /etc/mesosphere
          Creating role file for slave
          Configuring DC/OS
          Setting and starting DC/OS
          Warning: dcos-link-env.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
          Job for dcos-link-env.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status dcos-link-env.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Detailed log for the error is shown below

```
Sep 26 21:23:06 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethd6fa42c) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:23:07 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethd6fa42c) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:23:07 bootstrap kernel: veth616d8dc: renamed from eth0
Sep 26 21:23:07 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethd6fa42c) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:23:07 bootstrap kernel: device vethd6fa42c left promiscuous mode
Sep 26 21:23:07 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethd6fa42c) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:23:18 bootstrap kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[4723]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Sep 26 21:23:18 bootstrap kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[4723]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Sep 26 21:23:18 bootstrap kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[5001]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Sep 26 21:23:18 bootstrap systemd-udevd[6840]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth68e52a1: No such file or directory
Sep 26 21:23:18 bootstrap kernel: device veth63f5bef entered promiscuous mode
Sep 26 21:23:18 bootstrap kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth63f5bef: link is not ready
Sep 26 21:23:18 bootstrap systemd-udevd[6841]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth63f5bef: No such file or directory
Sep 26 21:23:19 bootstrap kernel: eth0: renamed from veth68e52a1
Sep 26 21:23:19 bootstrap kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth63f5bef: link becomes ready
Sep 26 21:23:19 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth63f5bef) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:23:19 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth63f5bef) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:23:25 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth63f5bef) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:23:25 bootstrap kernel: veth68e52a1: renamed from eth0
Sep 26 21:23:25 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth63f5bef) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:23:25 bootstrap kernel: device veth63f5bef left promiscuous mode
Sep 26 21:23:25 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth63f5bef) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:23:33 bootstrap kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[5001]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Sep 26 21:23:33 bootstrap kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[5001]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Sep 26 21:23:33 bootstrap kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[4724]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Sep 26 21:23:33 bootstrap systemd-udevd[6983]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for vethded8b56: No such file or directory
Sep 26 21:23:33 bootstrap systemd-udevd[6982]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth8d47246: No such file or directory
Sep 26 21:23:33 bootstrap kernel: device vethded8b56 entered promiscuous mode
Sep 26 21:23:33 bootstrap kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethded8b56: link is not ready
Sep 26 21:23:34 bootstrap kernel: eth0: renamed from veth8d47246
Sep 26 21:23:34 bootstrap kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethded8b56: link becomes ready
Sep 26 21:23:34 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethded8b56) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:23:34 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethded8b56) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:23:49 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethded8b56) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:23:49 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethded8b56) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:23:49 bootstrap kernel: veth8d47246: renamed from eth0
Sep 26 21:23:49 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethded8b56) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:23:49 bootstrap kernel: device vethded8b56 left promiscuous mode
Sep 26 21:23:49 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethded8b56) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:24:00 bootstrap kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[4723]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Sep 26 21:24:00 bootstrap kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[4723]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Sep 26 21:24:00 bootstrap systemd-udevd[7135]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth87ebff7: No such file or directory
Sep 26 21:24:00 bootstrap systemd-udevd[7136]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth88de99b: No such file or directory
Sep 26 21:24:00 bootstrap kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[6433]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Sep 26 21:24:00 bootstrap kernel: device veth88de99b entered promiscuous mode
Sep 26 21:24:00 bootstrap kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth88de99b: link is not ready
Sep 26 21:24:01 bootstrap kernel: eth0: renamed from veth87ebff7
Sep 26 21:24:01 bootstrap kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth88de99b: link becomes ready
Sep 26 21:24:01 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth88de99b) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:24:01 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth88de99b) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:24:16 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth88de99b) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:24:51 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth88de99b) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:24:51 bootstrap kernel: veth87ebff7: renamed from eth0
Sep 26 21:24:52 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth88de99b) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:24:52 bootstrap kernel: device veth88de99b left promiscuous mode
Sep 26 21:24:52 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth88de99b) entered disabled state
~
lines 1917-1972/1972 (END)
root@bootstrap:/root# fg
bash: fg: current: no such job
root@bootstrap:/root# journalctl -xe
Sep 26 21:23:06 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethd6fa42c) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:23:06 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethd6fa42c) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:23:07 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethd6fa42c) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:23:07 bootstrap kernel: veth616d8dc: renamed from eth0
Sep 26 21:23:07 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethd6fa42c) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:23:07 bootstrap kernel: device vethd6fa42c left promiscuous mode
Sep 26 21:23:07 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethd6fa42c) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:23:18 bootstrap kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[4723]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Sep 26 21:23:18 bootstrap kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[4723]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Sep 26 21:23:18 bootstrap kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[5001]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Sep 26 21:23:18 bootstrap systemd-udevd[6840]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth68e52a1: No such file or directory
Sep 26 21:23:18 bootstrap kernel: device veth63f5bef entered promiscuous mode
Sep 26 21:23:18 bootstrap kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth63f5bef: link is not ready
Sep 26 21:23:18 bootstrap systemd-udevd[6841]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth63f5bef: No such file or directory
Sep 26 21:23:19 bootstrap kernel: eth0: renamed from veth68e52a1
Sep 26 21:23:19 bootstrap kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth63f5bef: link becomes ready
Sep 26 21:23:19 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth63f5bef) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:23:19 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth63f5bef) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:23:25 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth63f5bef) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:23:25 bootstrap kernel: veth68e52a1: renamed from eth0
Sep 26 21:23:25 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth63f5bef) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:23:25 bootstrap kernel: device veth63f5bef left promiscuous mode
Sep 26 21:23:25 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth63f5bef) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:23:33 bootstrap kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[5001]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Sep 26 21:23:33 bootstrap kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[5001]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Sep 26 21:23:33 bootstrap kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[4724]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Sep 26 21:23:33 bootstrap systemd-udevd[6983]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for vethded8b56: No such file or directory
Sep 26 21:23:33 bootstrap systemd-udevd[6982]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth8d47246: No such file or directory
Sep 26 21:23:33 bootstrap kernel: device vethded8b56 entered promiscuous mode
Sep 26 21:23:33 bootstrap kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethded8b56: link is not ready
Sep 26 21:23:34 bootstrap kernel: eth0: renamed from veth8d47246
Sep 26 21:23:34 bootstrap kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethded8b56: link becomes ready
Sep 26 21:23:34 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethded8b56) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:23:34 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethded8b56) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:23:49 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethded8b56) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:23:49 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethded8b56) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:23:49 bootstrap kernel: veth8d47246: renamed from eth0
Sep 26 21:23:49 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethded8b56) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:23:49 bootstrap kernel: device vethded8b56 left promiscuous mode
Sep 26 21:23:49 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(vethded8b56) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:24:00 bootstrap kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[4723]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Sep 26 21:24:00 bootstrap kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[4723]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Sep 26 21:24:00 bootstrap systemd-udevd[7135]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth87ebff7: No such file or directory
Sep 26 21:24:00 bootstrap systemd-udevd[7136]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth88de99b: No such file or directory
Sep 26 21:24:00 bootstrap kernel: aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[6433]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Sep 26 21:24:00 bootstrap kernel: device veth88de99b entered promiscuous mode
Sep 26 21:24:00 bootstrap kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth88de99b: link is not ready
Sep 26 21:24:01 bootstrap kernel: eth0: renamed from veth87ebff7
Sep 26 21:24:01 bootstrap kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth88de99b: link becomes ready
Sep 26 21:24:01 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth88de99b) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:24:01 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth88de99b) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:24:16 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth88de99b) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 21:24:51 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth88de99b) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:24:51 bootstrap kernel: veth87ebff7: renamed from eth0
Sep 26 21:24:52 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth88de99b) entered disabled state
Sep 26 21:24:52 bootstrap kernel: device veth88de99b left promiscuous mode
Sep 26 21:24:52 bootstrap kernel: docker0: port 1(veth88de99b) entered disabled state
```

I'm new to these kind of things and please don't hesitant to ask question.